# Foreach inside foreach Wordpress MegaMenu

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am developing a website in HTML and using wordpress as CMS. I have implemented a menu nav in header, a MEGA MENU to be exact, but I need this " ul ", to be inside a "foreach" like "li a", because for each "ul" I need to create a column. I'm very beginner in PHP and would like to add a second "foreach" in that code, transforming the "ul" into a loop as well.

the code is here :

```html
<div class="mainmenu_area">
    <div class="container">
        <nav id="navigation1" class="navigation">
            <!-- toggle -->
            <div class="nav-header">
                <div class="nav-toggle"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Main Menus Wrapper -->
            <div class="nav-menus-wrapper">
                <ul class="nav-menu">
                    <?php $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
                    if ( isset( $locations['primary-menu']) ) {
                        $menu = get_term( $locations['primary-menu'], 'nav_menu');
                        if ( $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->name ) ) {
                            foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                                if ($item->menu_item_parent != 0) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                $curNavItemID = $item->ID;
                                $classList = implode(" ", $item->classes);
                                echo "<li class=\"{$classList}\">";
                                echo "<a href=\"{$item->url}\">{$item->title}</a>";
                                if ( in_array('has-mega-menu', $item->classes)) { ?>
                                <div class="megamenu-panel">
                                    <div class="megamenu-lists">

                                        <ul class="megamenu-list list-col-4">
                                        <?php 
                                        foreach ( $items as $subnav) {
                                            if ( $subnav->menu_item_parent == $curNavItemID) {
                                                echo "<li><a href=\"{$subnav->url}\">{$subnav->title}</a>";
                                            }
                                        } ?>


                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php }
                            echo '</li>';
                        }
                    }
                } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</div>
```

the html

```html
 <div class="mainmenu_area">
            <div class="container">
                <nav id="navigation1" class="navigation">
                    <!-- toggle -->
                    <div class="nav-header">
                        <div class="nav-toggle"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Main Menus Wrapper -->
                    <div class="nav-menus-wrapper">
                        <ul class="nav-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Cabelos</a>
                                <div class="megamenu-panel">
                                    <div class="megamenu-lists">
                                        <ul class="megamenu-list list-col-4">
                                            <h5>Sub-cat</h5>
                                            <li><a href="accordians.html" target="_blank">Accordions</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="alerts.html" target="_blank">Alerts</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="badges.html" target="_blank">Badges</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="blockquotes.html" target="_blank">Blockquotes</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="megamenu-list list-col-4">
                                            <h5>Sub-cat</h5>
                                            <li><a href="breadcumbs.html" target="_blank">Breadcrumbs</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="buttons.html" target="_blank">Buttons</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="forms.html" target="_blank">Forms</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="gallery.html" target="_blank">Gallery</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="megamenu-list list-col-4">
                                            <h5>Sub-cat</h5>
                                            <li><a href="headings.html" target="_blank">Headings</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="icon-fontawesome.html" target="_blank">Icon Fontawesome</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="icon-7-stroke.html" target="_blank">Icon 7 Stroke</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="labels.html" target="_blank">Labels</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <ul class="megamenu-list list-col-4">
                                            <h5>Sub-cat</h5>
                                            <li><a href="modals.html" target="_blank">Modals</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="paginations.html" target="_blank">Paginations</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="progress-bars.html" target="_blank">Progress Bars</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="tables.html" target="_blank">Tables</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Perfumes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Maquiagem</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cuidados para Pele</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Corpo e Banho</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Kits e Presentes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Outlet</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Marcas</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: But your code has an inner `foreach` that loops through the `li`'s of the inner `ul`... Can you specify what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not expressing me correctly. I need to repeat this 'ul' before the 'li' for up to four times, with the 'li' repeating itself inside it for endless times

Comment: edited with the html code.

Comment: I posted my desired

Comment: But your code already echoes an equivalent HTML structure :-)

Comment: Maybe you can specify what you mean with `transforming the "ul" into a loop`, but without using programming terms, but instead tell us about the menu you want to create. If you have a mockup for your menu it would help alot as well.

Comment: This code is taking the Wordpress menu with the 'has-mega-menu' class and creating a dropdown, but only with 1 list inside. I need it to create with 4 lists, just like I put in the wordpress menu, 1 link> 4 dropdowns inside> each dropdown with 1 list, but this code is only creating 1 list and ignoring the others

Comment: Where do you get the different subcategory data from?

Comment: It needs to be when creating the menu in wordpress. As soon as I put the first link and then just below I put the first list, so on the same line I would put the second and so on.